# .includes with two possible value options

Tags: google-apps-script

With only one value to search for the line of script I use is as follows:

```
if (!text.includes("Test 1")) return;
```

Is there an option if I have two different values that may be included? Like for example:

`"Test 1"` ***OR*** `"Test 2"`

> I didn't want to use if and else because it slows down the script, for having to create two copies of the rest of the script for if and else for each of the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the array like `["Test 1", "Test 2"]` and `every` in your situation? The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
var searchTexts = ["Test 1", "Test 2"];
if (searchTexts.every(e => !text.includes(e))) return;
```

- In this case, only when `text` includes both `Test 1` and `Test 2`, `searchTexts.every(e => !text.includes(e))` is `false`.
- When you want to retrieve `false` when at least, one of `Test 1` and `Test 2` is included in `text`, how about the following script?

  ```
    var searchTexts = ["Test 1", "Test 2"];
    if (!searchTexts.some(e => text.includes(e))) return;
  ```

#### References:

- [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
- [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: That's a good idea for using the `every` method.  Thanks. It takes a while to get a sense of where to apply the different methods.